# How to stop browser redrawing until DOM manipulation complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

At various points in my 1-page web app I want to do some fairly heavy DOM manipulation, moving various divs around (which each have lots of sub-elements). I don't want the browser trying to repeatedly redraw the page mid-manipulation. Is there a way to say to the browser "pause redrawing until I give the go ahead"?

requestAnimationFrame() seems like one candidate, but is that suitable for DOM rearranging, or just for animation? Are there any other things I could do?

Thanks

Comment: Unless you specifically introduce breakpoints with timeouts etc. then the browser automatically waits before rendering the DOM. Manually optimizing it isn't necessary or sensible.

Comment: There are events for things like drag that fire when it starts and stops. I would just build the app to fire the page rebuild on dragstop rather than drag. Or you can do things like this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/done-resizing-event/

Comment: The naive answer to your question would have terrible performance consequences, so I don't want to type it out. Can you provide some more details of the current flow of events and why this is a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using documentFragment.

1. Create the documentFragment.
2. Write everything into a documentFragment first.
3. When done, replace DOM content with documentFragment.

Then the manipulation does not take place on-the-fly, you use the documentFragment as a sort of buffer.